# Why is one of these prime number generators faster than the other?

Tags: python, time, any, primality-test

Recently interested in simple primality tests. I have the following two functions that return a list of all primes up to the given input. The first I made, the other is based off wikipedia's pseudocode for primality tests. I then slightly altered mine to be what I thought was the closest to wikipedia's.

When I time them (with 10000 as the input/limit), mine takes an order of magnitude longer than the other. I'm not quite sure why, as to me they're doing really similar things. Mine checks through a list of primes with "any", whereas wiki's checks through those same numbers but generates them with a while loop. What am I missing?

```
def my_primality(lim):                                                                                                                         
    count = 5                                                                                                                          
    slbprimes = [2,3];                                                                                                                 
    while count<lim:                                                                                                                   
        if count%3==0:                                                                                                                 
            pass                                                                                                                       
        elif any(count%i==0 for i in slbprimes if i**2<=count):                                                                        
            pass                                                                                                                       
        else:                                                                                                                          
            slbprimes.append(count)                                                                                                    
        count+=2                                                                                                                       
    return slbprimes 

def evenbetter(lim):                                                                                                                          
    count = 5                                                                                                                          
    ebprimes=[2,3];                                                                                                                    
    while count < lim:                                                                                                                 
        if count%3==0:                                                                                                                 
            count+=2                                                                                                                   
            continue                                                                                                                   
        i=5                                                                                                                            
        while i**2<=count:                                                                                                             
            if count%i==0 or count%(i+2)==0:                                                                                           
                count+=2                                                                                                               
                break                                                                                                                  
            i=i+6                                                                                                                      
        else:                                                                                                                          
            ebprimes.append(count)                                                                                                     
            count+=2                                                                                                                   
    return ebprimes
```

Comment: a little optimization in `my_primality` is using `for count in range(5,lim,2)` or `xrange` if you are in python 2, that way you avoid the constant checking of `count<lim` and get for free the `count+=2`

Comment: Oh, thank you. This is very true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`any` will traverse the whole list in order to see if any of the elements are evaluated to true. The `while` loop breaks faster, because it takes into account the elements are in increasing order. You can play with `takewhile` from `itertools` and you should get similar run time as the while loop.

Comment: So you're saying `any` does _not_ stop at the first true statement?

Comment: It stops if it finds true statement, but if there a no true statements it will try all elements in the array and will not take advantage that it can break early when `if i**2<=count` fails. The while loop does take advantage of that.